# Scraping infinite scrolling yahoo finance historical data

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** past 5 years yahoo finance historical data for a particular stock. I have implemented a python code that is **scraping** each row of the table containing historical data. I know there are simpler ways to fetch historical data but I want to do it with **scraping**. The problem is yahoo finance has infinte scrolling implmented in it i.e. as soon as I reach the end of the website more rows are getting added dynamically to the table. But my code is fetching rows till the end of first page only and not the complete 5 years data. Here is the sample of the code that I'm trying:

After navigating to the rows during **scraping** part-

```
tableRows = table.find_all('tr', class_='BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)')
```

I'm further extracting values from these rows

Comment: mind sharing the url?

Comment: url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/RELIANCE.NS/history?period1=1297987200&period2=1613606400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true'

Comment: FYI scrap/scrapping are about throwing away. Scrape/scraping are the correct terms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to imitate user behavior inside the browser in order to fetch the rest of the results.

1. You can use the [Selenium web driver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
2. Navigate to the end of the page unless no more results show up(this step requires Javascript, [example](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page)). During this step make sure that you wait for the AJAX request to complete, otherwise you might end up with unexpected behavior.
3. Once no more results show up, use the selector you are already using to retrieve the information

Comment: Hii.. U mean that I should add the code for JavascriptExecutor before I run my code to fetch information. Right? And could you please also specifiy what will be the import for JavaScriptExecutor?

Comment: Even if i manually scroll down to the page and then copy the url and apply my code, it's still fetching the result for only first page entries

Comment: @SiddharthBhatheja I will be able to provide a working example in about 5-6 hours if no one else does until then. Also I updated the link in the second step that doesn't use JavascriptExecutor, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the yfinance library (https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)

```
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

# get stock info
msft.info

# get historical market data
hist = msft.history(period="max")
```

Comment: I up-voted this answer.  It's absolutely the most efficient way to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is one way to do it. More efficient way is to query the data directly:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime

years = 5

dt= datetime.datetime.now()
past_date = datetime.datetime(year=dt.year-years, month=dt.month, day=dt.day)

url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/RELIANCE.NS'
headers= {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'formatted': 'true',
'crumb': 'J2oUJNHQwXU',
'lang': 'en-GB',
'region': 'GB',
'includeAdjustedClose': 'true',
'interval': '1d',
'period1': '%s' %int(past_date.timestamp()),
'period2': '%s' %int(dt.timestamp()),
'events': 'div|split',
'useYfid': 'true',
'corsDomain': 'uk.finance.yahoo.com'}



jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
result = jsonData['chart']['result'][0]

indicators = result['indicators']
rows = {'timestamp':result['timestamp']}
rows.update(indicators['adjclose'][0])
rows.update(indicators['quote'][0])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
               timestamp     adjclose  ...         open          low
0    2016-03-08 03:45:00   492.139252  ...   499.019806   499.019806
1    2016-03-09 03:45:00   499.183502  ...   505.211090   504.517670
2    2016-03-10 03:45:00   484.831451  ...   516.132568   499.762756
3    2016-03-11 03:45:00   486.149292  ...   502.685059   500.555237
4    2016-03-14 03:45:00   488.665009  ...   504.765320   501.719208
                 ...          ...  ...          ...          ...
1229 2021-03-01 03:45:00  2101.699951  ...  2110.199951  2062.500000
1230 2021-03-02 03:45:00  2106.000000  ...  2122.000000  2089.100098
1231 2021-03-03 03:45:00  2202.100098  ...  2121.050049  2107.199951
1232 2021-03-04 03:45:00  2175.850098  ...  2180.000000  2157.699951
1233 2021-03-05 09:59:59  2178.699951  ...  2156.000000  2153.050049

[1234 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Hii.. It seems like a good solution. I try it. Thank you so much. Just for knowledge as I'm new to data science, Is this thing not possible with the approach that I took i.e. finding html elements table by their classes (for e.g. finding table by its class first, and then finding all the rows of that table by their class and then programmatically extracting info from those rows using a for loop like i did?). Please let me know

Comment: It's still absolutely possible. Just a different way to go about it. The only issue with going the path of parsing html in that way is that you a) are limited to the data that's in the html, and b) restricted by the html structure (meaning if for whatever reason, if the host changes the html/site, it may cause an error in the code). IF there is an option to get the data via api or within the `<script>` tags, thats usually more robust as it will *almost always* be in json format. And more often than not will have even more meta data with it. but not wrong to do it with selenium or beautifulsoup

Comment: So just to clarify, this is usually the order I try to scrape. 1) check for api; 2) check if data in script tag; 3a) if it’s a <table> tag use pandas .read_html; 3b) if not a <table> tag (or need additional data, for example like href in <a> tag in <table>) use bs4 to parse data by tags; 4) use selenium to render page, then use pandas/bs4 to parse data; 5) see if same data can be found on a different website.

Answer (score 0):

A lot better solutions have been shown, but I'm just showing you how it can be done with pressing "END" key

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(6)


driver.get("https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/RELIANCE.NS/history?period1=1297987200&period2=1613606400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="consent-page"]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button').click()

history_table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Col1-1-HistoricalDataTable-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/table/tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
# while year >= 2020 - 5
while(int(history_table[-1].find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[0].text.split()[2]) >= 2020-5):
    history_table = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="Col1-1-HistoricalDataTable-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/table/tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.send_keys(Keys.END).perform()
```